# Unidentified PHP Variable with pdo Database Connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: WohFK in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projekt\Controller\controller.php on line 29

when i'm trying to Hand Over my Variable to the Controller

Select.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> // JQuery Reference
    <script
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/jqueryui/dataTables.jqueryui.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="example">
    <thead>
    <th>Geschlecht</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Nachname</th><th>Alter</th><th>Strasse</th><th>Hausnummer</th><th>Postleitzahl</th><th>Wohnort</th><th>Telefonnummer</th><th>Email</th><th>Webseite</th><th>Wohn</th><th>KontaktFK</th><th>Anpassungen</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $controller = new Controller();
    foreach($entries as $entry){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$entry['Geschlecht'].'</td><td>'.$entry['Vorname'].'</td><td>'.$entry['Nachname'].'</td><td>'.$entry['Alter'].'</td><td>'.$entry['Strasse'].'</td><td>'.$entry['Hausnummer'].'</td>
                <td>'.$entry['PLZ'].'</td><td>'.$entry['Ortsname'].'</td><td>'.$entry['Telefonnummer'].'</td><td>'.$entry['Email'].'</td><td>'.$entry['Webseite'].'</td><td class = "hidden">'.$entry['WohnortFK'].'</td><td>'.$entry['KontaktFK'].'</td>
                <td><a href="?c=Controller&a=Delete&WohFK='.$controller->Delete($entry['WohnortFK']).'">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>';

    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#example").dataTable();
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller.php:

```
class Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    include_once 'Model/Db.php';

}

public function form()
{
    include 'view/Erfassung.php';
}

public function Select()
{
    $Select = new datenverarbeitung();
    $entries = $Select->FetchData();
    include 'view/Select.php';
}

    public function Delete($WohFK)
    {
        echo $WohFK;
    }

    public function Datafetch()
    {
        $array = array();
        $Datasend = new datenverarbeitung();

        $array[0] = $_POST['Geschlecht'];
        $array[1] = $_POST['Vorname'];
        $array[2] = $_POST['Nachname'];
        $array[3] = $_POST['Alter'];
        $array[4] = $_POST['Telefonnummer'];
        $array[5] = $_POST['Email'];
        $array[6] = $_POST['Webseite'];
        $array[7] = $_POST['Strasse'];
        $array[8] = $_POST['Hausnummer'];
        $array[9] = $_POST['Postleitzahl'];
        $array[10] = $_POST['Wohnort'];
        $Datasend->InsertDataWohnort($array);
    }


    public
    function Test($WohFK)
    {
        echo $WohFK;
    }
}
```

Navigation.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['c'])){
    if(include 'controller/' . strtolower($_GET['c']) . '.php'){
                $controller = new $_GET['c']();
                if(isset($_GET['a']) &&
                                method_exists($controller, $_GET['a'])){
                        $controller->$_GET['a']();                          
                                }
    }else{
            echo 'Seite nicht gefunden';
    }
```

Comment: You dont call Controller::Delete() anywhere in the code you provided. Look again for line 29

Comment: Here i Call the Controller :
<td><a href="?c=Controller&a=Delete&WohFK='.$controller->Delete($entry['WohnortFK']).'">Delete</a></td>

Comment: where's the class that goes with this? You can't use public without a class declaration

Comment: Myru: Ok. Thats  text placed in a `href` attribute of an anchor tag. Where is the code that converts that to a call to the Delete method. It does not look like it is anywhere in this code

Comment: @Fred just added the complete Controller.php
and the Select.php

Comment: @RiggiFolly I also Added my Navigationsite, thats why i use the href

Comment: You should pass the argument: `$controller->$_GET['a']($_GET['WohFK'])`

Comment: @Gouda the variable $entries i'm using to insert data into a Jquery Datatable

Comment: Do you mean this line?

$entries = $Select->FetchData();

It's used to pass the select results from my DB-Model to the Select.php